# Wait-free queue implementation in C++

Tags: c++, concurrency, queue, nonblocking

Is it possible to implement a Concurrent Queue which is completely wait-free and can support simultaneously multiple writers and readers?I know I can use mutexes or an existing library, but I really want to implement it myself.Any ideas?

Comment: Boost implements the Michael-Scott queue since 1.53 I think.

Comment: I have a design for a single consumer single producer class, will this work? (I am pretty sure arbitrary numbers of consumers,producers is not doable without mutexes)

Comment: Threading Building Block (TBB) include several thread safe container.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: It is possible, modulo memory management concerns (it's tricky to know when to release a node). Apart from Michael-Scott, there are modified proposals by Fober-Orlarey-Letz worth checking out.

Comment: @DEIMOS: You probably know this, but it may not be the best idea to use a single MPMC structure. Better to avoid sharing altogether and give each thread a SPSC container (much faster), where the single consumer is a single harvester thread that collects all the thread-local queues.

Comment: Just keep in mind, wait free data structures tend to perform better than mutex-based structures only when there are no (or few) threads that can make forward progress without accessing the structure. Otherwise, the wait free logic just increases contention. That makes them good for "core" things like memory management that no thread can avoid touching but a bad choice for things not close to the core.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm not sure I understand, how can having multiple threads wait for a mutex be any better than having them access the wait-free data structure?

Comment: @Mehrdad Consider two cores and three threads, A1, A2, and B1. Threads A1 and A2 frequently access the same collection. Thread B1 does not. If thread A2 is waiting for a mutex, thread B1 can be scheduled, allowing threads A1 and B1 to run with no contention. A wait-free data structure will let A1 and A2 run together, frequently contending and performing poorly. The lock keeps the contending threads from running at the same time, with a performance benefit. The wait-free data structure actually maximizes contention by preventing conflicting threads from being descheduled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a wait-free queue for multiple enqueuers and dequeuers [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~sakogan/papers/ppopp11.pdf), but as @David Schwartz said this will not be necessarily faster just for being wait-free.
[This](http://www.par.univie.ac.at/project/peppher/publications/Published/opodis10lfq.pdf) is another paper about wait-free queue.
On the references of these papers you also can find other proposed queues based on arrays, that means they have a limited capacity, but they are faster than those based on lists.

If you are looking for a practical solution Michael and Scott's Lock-Free queue is probably a good alternative.

If you want to learn more and give it a try yourself, [Here](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues) you can find a good resume of the possible alternatives and there are a few code examples.